# Nestjs GraphQL Apollo Federation - resolver has an object in debug, returns an object with nulls

Tags: typescript, mongoose, graphql, nestjs, apollo-federation

I am using NestJs, GraphQL apollo federation (schema first approach) and Mongoose.

While querying for the `product` or `products` resolver, the query returns an object where all the properties are nulls.

However, while I debug and use a breakpoint in my service/resolver I can see that these functions are returning the correct mongo document(s).

Code snippets by file:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "product": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// product.graphql
type Product {
  id: String
  name: String
  displayName: String
  productId: Int
  partnerId: String
}

type Query {
  product(id: String): Product
  products: [Product]
}
```

```js
// product.model.ts
@MongooseSchema()
export class ProductDocument extends Document implements Product {
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId })
  @Transform((value) => value.toString())
  _id: string;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId })
  @Transform((value) => value.toString())
  id: string;

  @Prop()
  displayName: string;

  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  productId: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId })
  @Transform((value) => value.toString())
  partnerId: string;
}
```

```js
// products.resolvers.ts
import { Args, Query, Resolver, ResolveReference } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ProductsService } from './products.service';

@Resolver('Product')
export class ProductsResolvers {
  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {}

  @Query()
  async product(@Args('id') id: string) {
    const data = await this.productsService.findById(id);
    return data;
  }

  @Query()
  async products() {
    const res = await this.productsService.find();
    return res;
  }

  @ResolveReference()
  resolveReference(reference: { __typename: string; id: string }) {
    return this.productsService.findById(reference.id);
  }
}
```

```js
// auto generated graphql.ts
export interface Product {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    displayName?: string;
    productId?: number;
    partnerId?: string;
}

export interface IQuery {
    product(id?: string): Product | Promise<Product>;
    products(): Product[] | Promise<Product[]>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, I had two Interceptors that changed the response and broke the GraphQL API.